# give all integers between two numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, numbers, integer

Need some hints, how do i write a function called int_col that has one input argument, a positive integer n that is greater than 1, and one output argument v that is a column vector of length n containing all the positive integers smaller than or equal to n, arranged in such a way that no element of the vector equals its own index. In other words, v(k) is not equal to k for any valid index k.

i used this code

```
function v = int_col(n)
    v = [n:-1:1]'
end
```

but the solver is giving me error for input argument 3

Comment: This is not a site where we do your homework.

Comment: Consider taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how SO works.

Comment: i m not asking you to do that, i just want a hint about how to proceed

Comment: @alishaali No you are not.  Your question starts with "Write a function".  If you are asking for a hint then say so, and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: well i know how to generate random numbers between two numbers, but how do i generate all integers between two given integers

Comment: The colon operator `:` is your friend: `integerStart+1:integerEnd-1`

Comment: What's wrong with that code you have there?  It's correct.  That error you have provided is nonsense.

Comment: You can use `fliplr([1:n])`.

Comment: @CuriousMe it's unnecessary but a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Her is a solution using loops:

```
function v = int_col(n)

v = zeros(1,n);
for index=1:n
   val = randi(n);
   while (val == index || any(val == v))
       val = randi(n);
       if (index == n && (any(v == n) ~= 1))
           val = n;
           break
       end
   end
   v(index) = val;
   if (index == n && val == n)
      v(n) = v(n-1);
      v(n-1) = n;
   end
end
v = v';
end
```

Comment: which input did you use for n?

Comment: works fine for me, without error. Just copy my code and try in command window int_col(2) or int_col(3)

Comment: could it be that you are using this in another program and it needs a column vector instead of a row vector? then you just have to transpose the output of the code sample above

Comment: Thanx a lot for the help. I apologize if i was too direct in asking the question. this was my first time . Thank You

Comment: It's ok :) just try to add some code or approach you already tried next time you ask a question.

Comment: And if your solution works with the one liner v = [n:-1:1]' you could answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: By the way my solution is sometimes generating a endless loop: i.e:
input n = 3 and if the first two values of v are set to 2 and 1 then v=[2 1 0]
and the last value wont get filled.

Answer (score 0):

```
function[v]=int_col(n)
v=zeros(n,1);
k=1:n;
p=cat(2,k(n),k(1:n-1));
v=p'
end
```